# Extracting package-lock.json from release to reproduce build

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

### Context

I'm trying to apply some PRs to a VSCode plugin, but the original code lacks `package-lock.json` file and doesn't build anymore; even after applying a PR with compile fixes, the code does not work correctly. Inspecting the published plugin shows different dependency versions have been picked*, and the author of the PR suggested this might be the root problem.

*I've compared, e.g., the outputs of
`$ grep '_id' server/node_modules/*/package.json` in my local build, vs
`$ grep '_id' ~/.vscode/extensions/siegebell.vscoq-0.2.7/server/node_modules/*/package.json` on the version from the VSCode Marketplace, and they're pretty different.

### Question

Is there a good way to reconstruct the correct dependency versions (and modify `package.json` or `package-lock.json`)? Or is there a better way to reproduce the original build?
Beware, I'm a developer, but not a TypeScript/JavaScript developer.

My question is meant to be somewhat general, but if you want to see details of specific issues, the original issue and PR are https://github.com/siegebell/vscoq/issues/147 https://github.com/siegebell/vscoq/pull/148.

EDIT: FWIW, I aborted my attempt and the project was resurrected by an expert, tho somebody might find themselves in similar situations.

Comment: I haven't tested this but it might work. In the installed extension's folder, run `npm shrinkwrap`, copy the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to your dev folder, rename it to package-lock.json, delete all node_modules in your dev folder, then run `npm install`.